# Autofill SMS message in Phonegap/Cordova iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sms

Is there a way to automatically send an SMS with Phonegap or Cordova on iOS and Android? If not is there a way to pre fill the text message in the native app so the user just as to confirm the message to be sent?

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to KateMihalikova's answer (I don't have enough rep to add a comment on it) but her answer is correct except for the iOS >= 7 part; iOS 7 body is not supported (I believe only if you have already had history with the SMS number in question will it work, but I've not tested it); however iOS 8 has brought body prefill back: you have to replace the **;** that was used for iOS <=6 with an **&** instead:

**iOS 8:** `sms:+123456789&body=hello there`

Answer (score 3):

### `sms:` schema

**Android:** `sms:+123456789?body=hello there`

**iOS != 7:** `sms:+123456789;body=hello there`

**iOS = 7:** `sms:+123456789` - body is **not** supported

You can use link or javascript `location`:

```
<a href="sms:+123456789?body=hello there">Send SMS</a>
window.location = "sms:+123456789?body=" + encodeURIComponent("hello there");
```

Default sms app is opened and prefilled with provided data.

---

### Cordova plugin

Some examples:

- https://github.com/hazems/cordova-sms-plugin
- https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin

*Not tested*

<sub>9.3.2015 edited with iOS 8</sub>

Comment: Has anyone checked on iOS 8 supports body text?  The body text prefill is important

Comment: Still having iOS 7, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that with ios7 the body text will work as long as the number being contacted has an existing chat history.